# pymysql SELECT With WHERE Clause

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy, pymysql

I am trying to export MySql View to CSV file

Here is my code

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:@localhost:3306/user_database')
sql1 = "SELECT * FROM `users`"
#sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `SW`='Y'"
df = pd.read_sql(sql1, engine)
df.to_csv('sm_users.csv', index=False)
```

sql1 query work perfectly, but when I try to add WHERE clause it gives error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InternalError: (pymysql.err.InternalError) (1267, u"Illegal mix of collationssqlalchemy.exc.InternalError: (pymysql.err.InternalError) (1267, u"Illegal mix of collations
```

When I try to add WHERE condition to INT column it works but it does not work for the String Column.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Field names don't go in quotes `WHERE 'SW' ='Y'` is wrong

Comment: its not in single quotes, i used ` symbol, also i try with and without quotes but it showing same error.

Comment: You also got back ticks around table `users`. I've never seen bsck tick in any thing other than bash. No ` and some ' may be the solution

Comment: i tried it. but it giving same error, back ticks around table users is not a problem. As per i mentioned "SELECT * FROM `users_details`" works but if i tried to add WHERE clause it give the error.